# How to display calculation time above nodes?

Tags: node-editor, interface, geometry-nodes, performance

I was watching [a video tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZgFTmQlBX8Y?t=152) in which the author has his Geometry Nodes looking like this (screenshot):

[image]

Notice the `0.17ms` and `0.12ms` tabs with the timer icons above each node.

The time shown is the execution time for each node. So this will show where the bottleneck is in a slow node tree. I did some searching but have only come across developer discussions about the implementation of this feature. I have no idea which builds it's in or how to enable it. Is it available for Material Nodes too, or only Geometry Nodes? Etc...

So how can I enable this? It seems very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do this, simply activate the "Timings" option in the top right menu.

[image]

Note, however, that this is more of a guideline than a reliable indication of the computing time.

Changing the parameters in the node tree results in values that vary greatly in some cases. Repeating the test several times will eventually result in a useful average value for you.

Currently this display is only available at *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!